# Add show more and show less button when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

[how my output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95gLa.png)I am a Beginner! In my code i have one input area,text area and a button. according to my code it is displaying the inputs from text area inside a box(created using css). which only appears when we enter the data. Problem - now when we input from "id2" i.e if the "About" section exceeds 20 character i want to add a "show more" button at the beginning of 21st character and a show less button at the end too. also tell me a way to append the result similarly if we change the input field and press enter again.[my css code::](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRHTl.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SectionC-1.css">   
</head>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="id1"><br>
About:<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="id2"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="display()">Add New Book</button>
<div class ='container23' id = "msg">
<div id = "msg2">
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
function display(){
var name = document.getElementById("id1").value;
var about = document.getElementById("id2").value;
document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML ="<b>"+"Name :"+ name +" 
</b>"+ "<br>" + about;
}
</script>
```

how my code should look like will upload a picture for that

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code (text). Edit the post and use the `<>` button to create a [mre].